# Show selected row in alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, inputfield, checkbox

I have to show the selected row in an alert.
Can someone please help me?

Below is the page code snippet.

```
<tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!contactList}" var="contact" id="loop">
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="selecting" class="checkcell" type="radio" onclick="handleClick(this)"/></td>
                    <td style="font-family:  Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;"><div id="PlanName" >{!contact.Name}</div></td>
                    <td style="font-family:  Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;">{!contact.Parent_Account_Plan_abv__r.Name}</td>
                    <td style="font-family:  Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;">{!contact.Account_vod__r.Name}</td>
                    <td style="font-family:  Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;">{!contact.Status__c}</td>
                    <td style="font-family:  Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;">{!contact.Type__c}</td>

                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
```

Under script tag I am trying it this way.

```
         j$('[id$=selecting]').change(function() {
           j$('[id$=selecting]').not(this).prop('checked', false); 
           var val = j$('[id$=selecting]').val();
            handleClick(val);
            alert('Hi!'+val); 

        });

      function handleClick(el) {
      var parent = el.parentNode,
          cells = parent.querySelectorAll("td");
      console.log(cells[0].innerText);
      console.log(cells[1].innerText);
      console.log(cells[2].innerText);
      console.log(cells[3].innerText);
      console.log(cells[4].innerText);
                }
```

It gives me printed "Hi!on". I need to show the whole record selected here.

Comment: Sorry since I am operating from my smartphone, having edit issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the "entire record", you could either go up one node and query for them:

```
function handleClick(el) {
  var parent = el.parentNode.parentNode,
      cells = parent.querySelectorAll("td");
  console.log(cells[0].innerText);
  console.log(cells[1].innerText);
  console.log(cells[2].innerText);
  console.log(cells[3].innerText);
  console.log(cells[4].innerText);
}
```

Alternatively, you could consider using data attributes:

```
<input ... data-contact-name="{!HTMLENCODE(contact.Name)}" ...
```

Which you can then access in your code:

```
function handleClick(el) {
  console.log(el.dataset.contactName);
  ...
```

---

If you need to have the radio group work correctly without code, you will want to give them a name:

```
<input name="selecting" class="checkcell" type="radio" onclick="selected(this)"/>
```

This eliminates the need to use the unchecking trick for the other radios.

Comment: I have put your code in the script tag. But I am not getting the desired output. I am missing something as I get your solution must be the right one. Can you please help? I have updated my question.

Comment: @Testing_SFDC just take the bits inside the function and put them in your click handler. I wrote this just generically.

Comment: Yes I am trying that out. Please find my updated code in the question.

Comment: @Testing_SFDC Your onclick code is "selected".

Comment: Sorry I have changed it to onclick="handleClick(this)". Still the issue persists.

Comment: @Testing_SFDC what's the precise issue, though? Do you get an error? Have you tried any debugging?

Comment: @Testing_SFDC Thinking on it, I think it should have been `parent = el.parentNode.parentNode` instead.